# ListView Adapter with multiple Item layouts

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-adapter

I'm looking at adding a listview to my Android application with a thumbnail image.  The thumbnail on the left and text on the right.

Is there any way of populating the list view with seperate xml files, for example, could I have separate xmls for Austria, UK, USA etc and add them to the listview?

The reason I ask is, I plan to reuse the individual countries multiple times, as in, shown in an A to Z but then again by Continent etc.

If this is possible, could I get an example of how this is done or a link with a tutorial etc?

Thanks

Comment: Two things here: 1) You want to use custom adapter. 2) Why use XML for countries? why not SQLite database? Much easier and faster. (Basic tutorial on listview: http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429 )

Answer (score 9):

Do you really want separate .xml files? Or do you want to reuse one .xml file and just replace its content?

If you want separate .xml files (meaning multiple different Views in your Adapter)
take a look at the Adapters methods:

- **`getViewTypeCount()`**   - returns how many different view layouts you have
- **`getItemViewType(int pos)`**    - returns correct view type id by position

With these methods you can specify the number of different types in your adapter, and **load different layout files depending on the type.**

You could for example have an Adapter like this supporting multiple layouts. (e.g. one item being an actual item, the other one being a separator between the items)

**For more specific information, please take a look at this great tutorial:**

> http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296

Comment: what if i need the same xml but need  different data on the left and right side of the view in the same row.

Comment: @TerrilThomas Just inflate the xml file that you wish to use in your adapter and get the data that you wish to display from a sqlite db.

Comment: @Lunchbox : That means the data coming from the webservice first needs to be added in to the data base and then needs to be retrieved .

Comment: @TerrilThomas True, didn't know the data would be coming from a web service. You can extract the information into arrays and just use that. But if you navigate away from that page and go back to it again, the data still needs to be available. Otherwise you will need to call the web service each time the activity is loaded. Something to think about, lol